# How to get API Gateway client certificate inside CDK / Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Is it possible to retrieve the self-signed client certificate that API Gateway generates and then uses to communicate with HTTP proxy integrations? I'd like to be able to store the certificate in Parameter Store or Secrets Manager.

For example:

```
const clientCertificate = new CfnClientCertificate(this, "ApigClientCertificate", {
  description: "Client certificate presented by APIG when calling HTTPS backend services",
});

this.restApi = new SpecRestApi(this, 'OpenapiRestApi', {
  restApiName: 'My Api',
  apiDefinition: ApiDefinition.fromInline(...some OpenApi API defined here...),
  deploy: true,
  deployOptions: {
    stageName: 'api',
    clientCertificateId: clientCertificate.ref,
  },
});
```

Here I define an APIGateway by means of an OpenAPI spec, within which let's assume there is an HTTP proxy, where the user calls the APIG endpoint and that call is forwarded to the HTTPS endpoint with the self-signed client certificate generated by APIG.

Is it possible to get the PEM certificate from APIG?

Answer (score 0):

Its not yet possible as [AWS::ApiGateway::ClientCertificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-clientcertificate.html#aws-resource-apigateway-clientcertificate-syntax) does not return it.

You would have to develop a lambda function for [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) which would use AWS API [get-client-certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-client-certificates.html) to get the body of the cert and return to your stack.